# A Loop to display text when Button Pressed? PyGame

Tags: python, validation, loops, pygame

In PyGame, I only want to show text when a button is pressed, To have it as sort of a toggle, i.e. Press once Key E and show the text, press again to hide. I currently have the following code but does not do this? Any help is appreciated!

```
  for event in pygame.event.get():  
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_e:

                    if tile.G != 0:
                        Funk.text_to_screen(screen, tile.G, tile.x, tile.y + half, color = [120, 157, 40])
```

Comment: So it displays text on screen if tile.g is not 0, but I want it to display only if the User Pressed the e Key on there keyboard first?

Comment: @user3562041 from this code snippet, that's exactly what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything like that in the code snippet, so I'm going to suggest the following:

Create a variable, maybe something like

```
show_text = False

#more code
#while loop
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_e:
            if show_text == True:
                show_text = False
                #code to disable the text display
            else:
                show_text = True
                #code to enable text display
```

Where is

```
Funk.text_to_screen()
```

coming from? Haven't ever seen that. I would have used the font or freetype module to create the text surface and then blit it or not depending on whether the variable has been toggled or not.